# Show that term `cons` works by showing all beta reductions

Tags: functional-programming, lambda-calculus, cons

I'm new to functional programming.

So the terms `cons` appends an element to the front of the list. Where

```
cons ≜ λx:λl:λc:λn: c x (l c n)
```

How should I go about proving that `cons` works correctly using beta reduction for a sample function call? For example reducing `cons 3 [2,1]` to `[3,2,1]`?

Is there a formula like for the arithmetic operations in lambda calculus? I'm a bit confused on how to approach this compared to an arithmetic operation (i.e. addition or multiplication).

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can do equation transformations just like for arithmetic formulas. Lambda calculus just has different operators and rules.

Comment: Notice you haven't chosen the easiest-to-work-with list representation. You do understand what `λc:λn:` means?

Comment: I am not quite sure what λc:λn: means. Is it related to any of the list operations (i.e head, tail, nil)? Would you be able to give me an example of how the proof via beta reductions would look like for list 3[2,1]?

Comment: It's the [chuch encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding) of a list structure. Your list is `λc:λn: (c 3 (c 2 (c 1 n)))` (and I think in the definition of `cons` you swapped `l` and `c`). Now prove that this list is semantically equivalent to the result of evaluating `cons 3 (λc:λn: (c 2 (c 1 n)))`.

Comment: @Bergi `cons x l c n = c x (l c n)` is fine, anything seems to be swapped there.

Comment: @WillNess Oops, got myself confused there. `l` is not the second element of the list indeed, it's the function representing the rest of the list.

Comment: next question to ask is what can we do with such lists, can we `map` over them? `filter` them? `concat` them, flatten them? can we `sum` the elements in them or otherwise reduce the list with a binary function? can we `take` a given number of elements from them? but first, can we take their `head` and `tail`?...... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cons ≜ λx:λl:λc:λn: c x (l c n)` means that

```
cons x l c n =
   c x (l c n)
```

(in functional / applicative / combinatory notation). So

```
cons 3 [2,1] c n = 
 = c 3 ([2,1] c n)
```

and what is `[2,1]` if not just shortcut notation for `cons 2 [1]` so that we continue

```
 = c 3 (cons 2 [1] c n)
 = c 3 (c    2 ([1] c n))
 = c 3 (c    2 (cons 1 [] c n))
 = c 3 (c    2 (c    1 ([] c n)))
```

So there's no reduction from `cons 3 [2,1]` to `[3,2,1]`; `[3,2,1]` *is* `cons 3 [2,1]`. And `[2,1]` *is* `cons 2 [1]`, and `[1]` *is* `cons 1 []`.

The list `cons x xs`, when supplied with `c` and `n` arguments, *will* turn into `c x (xs c n)`, and so will `xs`, in its turn; so any list's elements are used in the  chain of applications of `c` on top one another.

And what should `[] c n` turn into? It has nothing in it to put through the `c` applications -- those are to be applied to a list's elements, and `[]` has none. So the only reasonable thing to do (and I'm sure you're already given that definition) is to turn `[] c n` into just `n`:

```
cons 3 [2,1] c n = 
 = c 3 (c    2 (c    1 ([] c n)))
 = c 3 (c    2 (c    1       n ))
```

whatever `c` and `n` *are*.

And that's that.